# Backbone: what's the point of a View that's never rendered?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone from someone else's Backbone app in combination with the documentation.  There are two things I don't understand about it that I can't figure out from the documentation. Hope someone might be able to explain...

**Gist of the app**
It's an app where you can drag and drop company names into boxes.

The app has a  Company View, a Company Model and a Companies Collection.

It also has a Bucket View, a Bucket Model, and Buckets Collection

It also has a general App View that's not associated with any model.

Problems...

**First- Is it weird that a view would never be rendered?**

The App View is instantiated like this

```
window.App = new AppView();
```

and it gets different things going in the app (populating the buckets with company names etc and setting up some events). However, the App View is never rendered.  The Bucket View and the Company View, on the other hand,  are both rendered at different points in the code. For example,

```
  var view = new BucketView({model: bucket});
  this.$("#bucket-list").append(view.render().el);
```

But never that App View. This App View also has no render function.  So is it weird that it has a View that's never rendered? Should its code be somewhere else?

**Second** Considering that App view is never rendered, is there any reason why they would have to change the default setting of `el` to the name of the main container div in the layout?  For example, in the App view, they do this...

```
el: $("#mainapp"),
```

However, if this view's never rendered, is there any reason to change the default setting of `el`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a Backbone.View instance normally, it will immediately generat an `el` on the view for you. This is used as the placeholder for all of the HTML that the view will manage, and you generally populate the view's `el` with your HTML in the render method, as you've already noted.

In some cases, though, you don't want to render a completely new set of HTML elements. Instead, you'll want to manage some existing HTML that's already part of the DOM. In this case, you can easily attach a backbone view to the existing DOM element by specifying the `el` in the constructor, as you've shown with the `el: $("#mainapp")` line.

When a Backbone view sees that it already has an `el`, it does not generate it's own. Instead, it uses what it was handed.

So, to directly answer your two questions:

#### 1) First- Is it weird that a view would never be rendered?

No, because ...

#### 2) if this view's never rendered, is there any reason to change the default setting of el?

The question is slightly off in a manner that that can't be directly answered. In reality, the view is never rendered *because* they are setting the `el` in the call to the constructor.

Comment: thanks...one thing I never mentioned. the view never renders anything into the el: $("#mainapp")...how could it then "manage some existing html", as you put it? am I missing something?

Comment: the Backbone view will basically take control of the `#mainapp` element. any html elements that exist within #mainapp will be directly available to the view, and the view's events, etc. this blog post might help you see what's happening: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/26/seo-and-accessibility-with-html5-pushstate-part-2-progressive-enhancement-with-backbone-js/